# Dynamically instantiate a class based on that classes name, in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a group of classes, each of which has a member called `Description`.
I would like the end-user of my library to be able to specify which classes they are interested and be able to read that description. Hence I want to be able to dynamically instantiate each of the specified classes and return the `Description`.

I'm aware that I need reflection to do this and I've seen a lot of SO questions suggesting `Class.forName` can help me but I haven't been able to get it working.

Hopefully the following demonstrates what I want to be able to do:

```
scala> abstract class Feature (start: Short, end: Short){val description: String}
defined class Feature

scala> class Feature1 (start: Short, end: Short) extends Feature(start, end){override val description = "this is feature 3"}
defined class Feature1

scala> class Feature2 (start: Short, end: Short) extends Feature(start, end){override val description = "this is feature 2"}
defined class Feature2

scala> class Feature3 (start: Short, end: Short) extends Feature(start, end){override val description = "this is feature 3"}
defined class Feature3

scala> val classesForWhichIWantToGetTheDescription = Set[String]("Feature1", "Feature2")
classesForWhichIWantToGetTheDescription: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(Feature1, Feature2)

scala> val classesWithDescriptions = classesForWhichIWantToGetTheDescription.map(
     |     className => (className, s"I want the class description of ${className} to be displayed here")
     | )
classesWithDescriptions: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(String, String)] = Set((Feature1,I want the class description of Feature1 to be displayed here), (Feature2,I want the class description of Feature2 to be displayed here))

scala> classesWithDescriptions.foreach(
     |     c => println(c)
     | )
(Feature1,I want the class description of Feature1 to be displayed here)
(Feature2,I want the class description of Feature2 to be displayed here)
```

Can anyone help me achieve this?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you don't have too many classes, you could have a `Map[String, () => Feature]`

Comment: I do have a lot of classes, a lot more than in this contrived example

Comment: altho now you say it, that MIGHT be an option. I would just prefer to not to have to go and update the map each time a new Feature gets added. Hence why looking at a solution using reflection.

Comment: Could you post a solution using your `Map[String, () => Feature]` suggestion anyway? I'ma  total Scala noob so not sure how to do this.

Comment: Link to Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ygKZ3vVlSIiWs3kgB1ZLSA

Comment: Why getting classes through names? That is slow, insecure, and unsafe. Why not just let the users import the classes they need?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The end users aren't writing Scala code. This library will be used by data scientists that use PySpark hence my ultimate aim here is to expose a list of features, with descriptions, that they can specify from their Python code. They do so as a list of strings, that list gets passed back to my Scala library via py4j. Thus, the end users cannot import the classes.

Comment: Never knew about Scastie. Very nice, thank you to the person that linked to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
val classesWithDescriptions = classesForWhichIWantToGetTheDescription.map(
  className => {
    val clazz = Class.forName(className)
    val field = clazz.getDeclaredField("description")
    field.setAccessible(true)
    val constructor = clazz.getConstructor(classOf[Short], classOf[Short])
    val instance = constructor.newInstance(0: Short, 0: Short)
    val description = field.get(instance)
    (className, s"description of $className: $description")
  }
)
```

Comment: thx. When I tried that I got an error, not sure what I'm missing: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/TXVOnw0YQkygMigxIrY9BQ

Comment: @jamiet In Scastie, you should prefix your class names with `Playground$`, like `Playground$Foo`

Comment: @jamiet Try this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/uy5pBsegTrau4ZosrghtBw. The answer will perfectly in a normal application. It'll also work if you turn Worksheet mode off: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PA9z93R9QPeAtJlMyWM95w

Comment: Fantastic, thank you, your suggestion worked and I modified it very slightly : https://scastie.scala-lang.org/l9zhIdbsSFm2QK9H4oNi7g